# Как исправить тип кода?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, файлы

Скопировал код скрипта с `HTML` на отдельный на `markerAnimation.js` после копировки `IDEA` предложила что-то поменять в `.js` из под корня, только я не понял что, и случайно нажал на Accept вместо Dismiss, и он код полностью поменял цвет, и вот что из этого получилось....[image: markerAnimation.js]

Как это исправить? Вернуть обратно? Я удалял данный файл снова под другими названиями создавал, все равно так же... Но до этого все было нормально...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не в типе кода. IDE указывает вам на синтаксическую ошибку в JS. Видите, красным подчеркнуто? Там же и подсказка будет при наведении.

Для проверки удалите вторую строку (с красными подчеркиваниями) и увидите, как стиль кода преобразится.

Дело в том, что вы скопировали код вместе со спец. вставками (которые окружены тегами <% ... %>) из шаблона. Эти вставки нужно заменить на числовые значения долготы и широты.

Comment: Даа, я сделал так, получилось, но скрипт не работал к сожалению( но я нашел другой способ узнал как это дело провернуть) убрал эти `<%=/jsp.tag%>` запихнул весь этот код одну функцию где он примит два переменных) А в JSP прописал `<script>MapMarkerAnimation(<%=lat,lng%>)</script>` Сработало на изи) но твой ответ верен) спасибо) Прикол в том что, я не понял на что в IDEA нажал, он поменялся совсем) будто JSP+JS стало... Так как в JavaScript нет такой команды: `request.getAttribute(.......)`

Comment: Иии нет, это совсем не шаблон) я просто изначально написал его прям в JSP скопировал в отдельный `.js` файл, и он был в нормальном состоянии, потом пришлось там кое что поменять, менял менял и вдруг наверху желтое уведомление выскочило, я случайно нажал на Accept, и тут IDEA подлагивать чет начал, и вижу код весь в ошибках... Странно да?